# AngularJS application can`t get List from Server (Java Spring)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, jackson

I try to load `List<Pick>` to my front-end application form server. On Server I have Spring application and I use hibernate to load picks objects from database

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web2/getActivePicks", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Pick>  getActivePicks() {
    PickDAO pd = new PickDAO();
    List<Pick> picks = pd.getPicksFrom(new Date()); 
    return picks;   
}
```

When I try to get this picks list I get `

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: 
(was java.lang.NullPointerException) 
(through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;com.gepick.app.objects.rmo.Pick[&quot;match&quot;]-&gt;com.gepick.app.objects.rmo.soccer.Match_soccer[&quot;ar&quot;]); 
nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) 
(through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;com.gepick.app.objects.rmo.Pick[&quot;match&quot;]-&gt;com.gepick.app.objects.rmo.soccer.Match_soccer[&quot;ar&quot;])
```

My pick class:

```
@Entity
public class Pick {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int pid;

@OneToOne
private Match_soccer match;

@OneToOne
private Algo1 algo;

@Column(length = 100)
private String pick;

@Column(length = 5)
private double plimit;
....
```

I change controller to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web2/getActivePicks", method =     RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JSONArray  getActivePicks() {
    PickDAO pd = new PickDAO();
    JSONArray picks = new JSONArray(pd.getPicksFrom(new Date()));
    return picks;   
}
```

But now i get http status 406 and messgae:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses 
with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when `Jackson`, your `JSON` *mapper* is trying to convert a `Pick` instance, the `Match_soccer` is null and that throws an exception.

You could either see that your `Match_soccer` is initialized before the *mapping* or you could **annotate** your `Pick` class with this `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`.

[This](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) will instruct the *mapper* to ignore all the **null** fields from the *mapping*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spring has no default way to convert a `List` into JSON, so it's failing to pass it over REST.  Can you convert it into a `JSONArray` first?

Comment: I change controller, look up :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with match object because hr and ar properties is null.